# Rust newbie question about string replacement

Tags: rust

```
fn get_filename_from_url(url: &str, extension: &str) -> str {
    let dt = chrono::Local::now();
    let cleaned_url = url
        .replace("https://", "")
        .replace("/", "-")
        .replace("?", "-")
        .as_str();
    return format!(
        "{}{}_{}{}",
        OUTPUT_FOLDER,
        cleaned_url,
        dt.format("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S"),
        extension
    )
    .as_str();
}
```

I get errors such as:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/scraper.rs:14:57
   |
14 | fn get_filename_from_url(url: &str, extension: &str) -> &str {
   |                               ----             ----     ^ expected named lifetime parameter
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I was also interested to see [Is there a safe / sanitised filename function in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973219/is-there-a-safe-sanitised-filename-function-in-rust) but didn't see a helpful example.

Comment: I notrice that the return type in the error message does not match the code in your snippet – `str` vs `&str`. I assume that you are asking about the code in the error message.

Comment: I just realize that your problem is something else. You should return a `String`, and remove the `as_str()` at the end of the function. I'll add a better duplicate.

Comment: I've added another duplicate. Let me know whether this answers your questions.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I couldn't figure out it out from the links, but your comment helped me. Thanks. This works: `fn get_filename_from_url(url: &str, extension: &str) -> String {
    
    let dt = chrono::Local::now();
    let cleaned_url = url
        .replace("https://", "")
        .replace("/", "-")
        .replace("?", "-");
    return format!(
        "{}{}_{}{}",
        OUTPUT_FOLDER,
        cleaned_url,
        dt.format("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S"),
        extension
    );
}`